# Sorting ObjectIDs in a nested array of MongoDB document by their creation date?

Tags: mongodb, nosql, aggregation-framework

I have a two collections `Conversation`s and `Message`s and each `Conversation` document has a nested array of `ObjectId`s of `Message`s documents. I want to fetch first 100 recent `Message`s. Their schema is roughly like this

```
Message = {
  body: String
  createdAt: Date
}

Conversation = {
  messages: [ObjectId]
}
```

And I want to store `Message` ids in sorted, from *recent to oldest* order in that nested array.

One solution I can think of, is simply insert new `ObjectId` at the front of the array, so that I get most recent `Message`s.

Or instead of storing ids in a array in `Conversation` document, I should store a reference to `Conversation` document in a `Message` document field and use that to find messages and sort them like this

```
db.messages.find({conversation: convId}).sort({createdAt: -1})
```

Is there any way I can use that `createdAt` field in `Message` document to store ids in sorted order?

Need help.

Comment: `sort({'messages.createdAt': -1})`

Comment: Will you please elaborate? @D.SM